# subsetting by multi-column index/key in dplyr (have data.table soln)

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

I'm looking to find a way to subset (or rethink how I handle the task) the following situation to stay in dplyr rather than "resort" to data.table as much of my analysis before/after this chunk is done in dplyr.

Situation: given a simulated dataset with multiple replications I would like to subset/dplyr::filter based on a two column key (ID and REP).

```
libs <- c("dplyr", "data.table")
lapply(libs, require, character.only = T)

# minimally reproducible example

# dataset
dat <- expand.grid(ID = 1:3, REP = 1:5, TIME = 1:3)
dat <- dat[order(dat$REP, dat$ID, dat$TIME),]
dat$CONC <- runif(nrow(dat), 1, 10)

# key/index
set.seed(1235)
ID_sample <- sample(unique(dat$ID), size = 5, replace = TRUE)
REP_sample <- sample(unique(dat$REP), size = 5, replace = TRUE)
key <- data.frame(ID = ID_sample, REP = REP_sample)


# data table solution
dt <- data.table(dat)
setkey(dt, ID, REP)
dt_subset <- dt[J(key)]
```

The data.table solution results in the following:

initial data structure:

```
   ID REP TIME     CONC
1   1   1    1 1.310819
2   1   1    2 2.371361
3   1   1    3 7.621165
4   2   1    1 1.010229
5   2   1    2 4.520830
6   2   1    3 5.162452
...
40  2   5    1 6.629885
41  2   5    2 9.680233
42  2   5    3 8.445726
43  3   5    1 3.835254
44  3   5    2 2.917229
45  3   5    3 7.592465
```

generated key and resulting subset:

```
> key
  ID REP
1  1   3
2  2   3
3  1   4
4  3   3
5  3   2

> dt[J(key)]
    ID REP TIME     CONC
 1:  1   3    1 3.038205
 2:  1   3    2 5.361020
 3:  1   3    3 8.137065
 4:  2   3    1 1.053889
 5:  2   3    2 2.689412
 6:  2   3    3 7.136503
 7:  1   4    1 9.137392
 8:  1   4    2 6.556821
 9:  1   4    3 2.206285
10:  3   3    1 4.330937
11:  3   3    2 4.254630
12:  3   3    3 8.819154
13:  3   2    1 4.508456
14:  3   2    2 7.286893
15:  3   2    3 5.896521
```

Is there a way of using this multi-column index to filter in dplyr?

The only 'solution' I've thought of so far is is to create a new column like so:

```
dat <- transform(dat, ID_REP = paste0(ID, '_', REP))
KEY <- paste0(ID_sample, '_', REP_sample)
filter(dat, ID_REP %in% KEY)
```

which works:

```
       ID REP TIME     CONC ID_REP
1   3   2    1 4.029622    3_2
2   3   2    2 5.786582    3_2
3   3   2    3 2.846836    3_2
4   1   3    1 4.968823    1_3
5   1   3    2 6.940782    1_3
6   1   3    3 5.017697    1_3
7   2   3    1 7.571442    2_3
8   2   3    2 6.350095    2_3
9   2   3    3 3.924427    2_3
10  3   3    1 6.360991    3_3
11  3   3    2 3.273693    3_3
12  3   3    3 4.029781    3_3
13  1   4    1 6.617855    1_4
14  1   4    2 1.910202    1_4
15  1   4    3 5.496817    1_4
```

but is inelegant and does not provide an easily extensible solution.

Comment: subset within `aggregate`? also you set.seed before runif, so we can't get the same data.

Comment: what do you mean we can't get the same data? thats why I set the seed? You can literally copy-paste my code to reproduce my entire example. Unfortunately I'm not trying to aggregate, I'm trying to subset the entire data frame for further analysis of only that subset

Comment: `dat$CONC <- runif(nrow(dat), 1, 10)

# key/index
set.seed(1235)`    you set the seed after you used a random operator

Comment: ohhh I see - sorry, that part is irrelevant (value-wise) - the reason I set the seed was to get the same key'd values (ID/REP) for the subsetting, which is what I care about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a [semi join](http://sqlity.net/en/1348/a-join-a-day-the-left-semi-join/):

```
semi_join(dat, key)
```

Comment: just did a microbenchmark on a 1.2mil row x 8 col dataframe comparing dplyr to data.table solutions - dplyr was a cool 2.5x faster!

Comment: @dpastoor, I'm guessing you're comparing with 1.8.10. Be sure to take a look at the next version of data.table (which'll be out soon, 1.9.0) and the benchmarks that'll soon follow.

Comment: @Arun will do - I put up the comparison [here on rpubs](http://rpubs.com/dpastoor/dplyr_vs_datatable) and will update w/ 1.9. I'll be honest, there may be a faster way of doing about it in dt - I am unfamiliar w/ the syntax - I was just doing the most logically similar operation that works

Comment: @dpastoor, thanks for the link. Will test on 1.9.0 later. It's in `ms` which doesn't mean much (bet. 150 and 350ms) to me personally. Because the time for `data.table(.)` alone (which you include in the benchmark) will be larger than the time to `join` in these cases. Given that `fread` can be used to get a `data.table` directly and 1.9.0 exports `setDT` function that converts `data.frame` to `data.table` *by reference*, getting a `data.table` wouldn't normally cost at all. Therefore I suggest benchmarking the `key + join` alone.

Comment: @Arun thanks I'll give it a try and update. I'll throw in an Rprof of the code when 1.9 comes out and I update it. As to the difference (150 vs 350 ms), I completely agree. I was mostly just happy to get away from my 20 second for loop I had hacked together initially (yuck!).

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you want the sum of the `CONC` variable for each key,

```
    aggregate(CONC~ID+REP+TIME,data=subset(dat,dat$ID %in% key$ID & dat$REP %in% key$REP),sum)
```

does that give you what you want?

Comment: Unfortunately not :-( If you ask for multiple subsets via '&' it doesn't work because it needs specific combinations of the two columns. By doing dat$ID %in% key$ID & dat$REP %in% key$REP it gives me all possible combinations ex: If I want two individuals represented by ID 1 REP 1 and ID 2 REP 3, using your combination I would get ID 1 REP 1, ID 1 REP 3, ID 2 REP 1, and ID 2 REP 3 since your the two %in% vectors are independent