# Subset a data frame based on value pairs stored in independent ordered vectors

Tags: r, subset

I have an R dataframe that I need to subset data from. The subsetting will be based on two columns in the dataframe. For example:

```
A <- c(1,2,3,3,5,1)
B <- c(6,7,8,9,8,8)
Value <- c(9,5,2,1,2,2)
DATA <- data.frame(A,B,Value)
```

This is how DATA looks

```
A B Value
1 6     9
2 7     5
3 8     2
3 9     1
5 8     2
1 8     2
```

I want those rows of data for which (A,B) combination is (1,6) and (3,8). These pairs are stored as individual (ordered) vectors of A and B:

```
AList <- c(1,3)
BList <- c(6,8)
```

Now, I am trying to subset the data basically by comparing if A column is present in AList **AND** B column is present in BList

```
DATA[(DATA$A %in% AList & DATA$B %in% BList),]
```

The subsetted result is shown below. In addition to the value pairs (1,6) and (3,8) I am also getting (1,8). Basically, this filter has given me value pairs for all combinations in AList and BList. How do I restrict it to just (1,6) and (3,8)?

```
A B Value
1 6     9
3 8     2
1 8     2
```

This is my desired result:

```
A B Value
1 6     9
3 8     2
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21916354/subsetting-by-multi-column-index-key-in-dplyr-have-data-table-soln/21943478#21943478

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could try `match` which an appropriated `nomatch` argument:

```
sub <- match(DATA$A, AList, nomatch=-1) == match(DATA$B, BList, nomatch=-2)
sub
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

DATA[sub,]
#  A B Value
#1 1 6     9
#3 3 8     2
```

A `paste` based approach would also be possible:

```
sub <- paste(DATA$A, DATA$B, sep=":") %in% paste(AList, BList, sep=":")
sub
# [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

DATA[sub,]
#  A B Value
#1 1 6     9
#3 3 8     2
```

Comment: Good approaches. After some testing: The `match`approach fails for cases when the same value repeats in the AList/BList vector as it only returns the positions of first match. The `paste` approach is more correct in that sense.

Comment: @RazorXsr: Good point against `match`. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 10):

This is a job for `merge`:

```
KEYS <- data.frame(A = AList, B = BList)
merge(DATA, KEYS)

#   A B Value
# 1 1 6     9
# 2 3 8     2
```

---

**Edit**: after the OP expressed his preference for a logical vector in the comments below, I would suggest one of the following.

Use `merge`:

```
df.in.df <- function(x, y) {
  common.names <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
  idx <- seq_len(nrow(x))
  x <- x[common.names]
  y <- y[common.names]
  x <- transform(x, .row.idx = idx)
  idx %in% merge(x, y)$.row.idx
}
```

or `interaction`:

```
df.in.df <- function(x, y) {
  common.names <- intersect(names(x), names(y))
  interaction(x[common.names]) %in% interaction(y[common.names])
}
```

In both cases:

```
df.in.df(DATA, KEYS)
# [1] TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Comment: This ultimately points out that storing the AList/BList in the current fashion is probably not the best way to go about it.

Comment: @RazorXsr, what was it you did not like about `merge`? sgigg's answer is helpful but it really is trying to reinvent the wheel. `merge` is already here for you: vetted, general and flexible. My two cents.

Comment: @flodel: Nothing against `merge` - but I was dealing with Spatial lines and points data objects (from `sp` package) and these values were deeply embedded within slots. sgigg's approach gave me a logical vector that I could use to subset the entire object while merge does not lend itself that well in this situation. When dealing with just plain data frames `merge` approach is definitely better.